# Is this Gutter install right?

Tags: gutters, fascia

Today, I found my home has a gutter install as below:
[image]

My question is:

1. The hanger screw has penetrate through the metal drip edge and gutter the fascia (cover), is it right? I am thinking it should go below the metal drip edge to avid damage meta drip edge.
2. The gutter installed almost above the fascia board, reach to the meta drip edge already. I am thinking water will leak out to fascia board later if gutter has been clogged.
3. The fascia has covered almost the whole fascia board, Is it good for fascia board protection? or if it should run below the gutter hanger screw?

Is it right now? if not, how should I fix it?

Comment: gutter should not too low to avoid water flash out of the gutter. drip edge usually 2'' long, so if screw lower than drip edge, water will flash out the gutter.

Comment: No matter what if the gutter gets clogged the gutter will overflow. If the nail or screw is lower the gutter will leak. Most gutters are hung with the nails or screws within 1" of the top of the metal depending on the forming machine. DIY models or sectional are at the top on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Many people call many metal shapes "drip edge". First of all, there is "drip edge" there. I don't know if that's just a quick drawing you drew, but you should have an overhang out of the roof on a drip edge.
Examples:

[image]
[image]

The hanger normally goes through the back of the gutter anyway, but not the drip edge. With an actual drip edge, even if installed the same way as shown, the overhang would help out with the water dripping, and you wouldn't have an issue. That being said, it doesn't mean that you will.

2 - It could.

3 - Good for protection.

4 - If the flange was part of the gutter, made from one piece, you cold have a roof mounted hanger, that's best case scenario, but just replacing that edge metal with a drip edge may be the ticket, that is IF you have issues.

Comment: you are right! I didn't notice  that when I draw the graph!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before.  I think it's because for long gutter runs they drop off so much for slope that they don't want it to get too far below the drip edge by the time it's done (to prevent splashes?)

Seems the most common thing is to just drill straight through the drip edge on the brackets.

I like the picture, very clear.  Most commonly I've heard the board referred to as the "fascia" and the cover to the "fascia board" as "fascia trim" or "flashing" or something like that, FWIW.

refs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-4hX1fvYY0 https://www.reddit.com/r/Roofing/comments/xcueqq/was_this_gutter_install_done_correctly_okay_to/